CGLM Not Rendering with Sokol
I've setup cglm from a wrap configured with Meson, and have copied one of the samples from https://github.com/floooh/sokol-samples/tree/master (cube-sapp, to be exact). I've tried to replace sokol's use of HandMadeMath, with cglm; for some reason however, nothing renders to the screen other than a blue clear color.
Any clue on what's going on?
The main.c file

#include <cglm/cglm.h>  // Include cglm for math functions
#include <sokol.h>

#include "cube-sapp.h"
static struct {
    float rx, ry;
    sg_pipeline pip;
    sg_bindings bind;
} state;

void init(void) {
    sg_setup(&(sg_desc){
        .environment = sglue_environment(),
        .logger.func = slog_func,
    });

    /* cube vertex buffer */
    float vertices[] = {
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,

        -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,
        0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,

        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  -1.0,
        0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
        1.0,  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,

        1.0,  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,  0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0,
        1.0,  0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.5,  0.0,
        1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  1.0,  0.5,  0.0,  1.0,

        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,  0.5,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        0.0,  0.5,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.5,  1.0,
        1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,  0.5,  1.0,  1.0,

        -1.0, 1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.5,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  1.0,
        1.0,  0.0,  0.5,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.5,
        1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.5,  1.0};
    sg_buffer vbuf = sg_make_buffer(&(sg_buffer_desc){
        .data = SG_RANGE(vertices), .label = "cube-vertices"});

    /* create an index buffer for the cube */
    uint16_t indices[] = {0,  1,  2,  0,  2,  3,  6,  5,  4,  7,  6,  4,
                          8,  9,  10, 8,  10, 11, 14, 13, 12, 15, 14, 12,
                          16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, 22, 21, 20, 23, 22, 20};
    sg_buffer ibuf =
        sg_make_buffer(&(sg_buffer_desc){.type = SG_BUFFERTYPE_INDEXBUFFER,
                                         .data = SG_RANGE(indices),
                                         .label = "cube-indices"});

    /* create shader */
    sg_shader shd = sg_make_shader(cube_shader_desc(sg_query_backend()));

    /* create pipeline object */
    state.pip = sg_make_pipeline(&(sg_pipeline_desc){
        .layout =
            {/* test to provide buffer stride, but no attr offsets */
             .buffers[0].stride = 28,
             .attrs = {[ATTR_cube_position].format = SG_VERTEXFORMAT_FLOAT3,
                       [ATTR_cube_color0].format = SG_VERTEXFORMAT_FLOAT4}},
        .shader = shd,
        .index_type = SG_INDEXTYPE_UINT16,
        .cull_mode = SG_CULLMODE_BACK,
        .depth =
            {
                .write_enabled = true,
                .compare = SG_COMPAREFUNC_LESS_EQUAL,
            },
        .label = "cube-pipeline"});

    /* setup resource bindings */
    state.bind = (sg_bindings){.vertex_buffers[0] = vbuf, .index_buffer = ibuf};
}

void frame(void) {
    /* NOTE: the vs_params_t struct has been code-generated by the
     * shader-code-gen */
    vs_params_t vs_params;
    const float w = sapp_widthf();
    const float h = sapp_heightf();
    const float t = (float)(sapp_frame_duration() * 60.0);

    /* Using cglm for matrix operations */
    mat4 proj, view, rxm, rym, model;
    glm_perspective(glm_rad(60.0f), w / h, 0.01f, 100.0f, proj);

    glm_lookat((vec3){0.0f, 1.5f, 6.0f}, (vec3){0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
               (vec3){0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}, view);
    glm_translate(view, (vec3){0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f});

    state.rx += 1.0f * t;
    state.ry += 2.0f * t;
    glm_rotate(rxm, glm_rad((float)state.rx), (vec3){1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f});
    glm_rotate(rym, glm_rad((float)state.ry), (vec3){0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f});
    glm_mat4_mul(rxm, rym, model);
    glm_mat4_mulN((mat4*[]){&proj, &view, &model}, 3, vs_params.mvp);

    sg_begin_pass(&(sg_pass){
        .action =
            {
                .colors[0] = {.load_action = SG_LOADACTION_CLEAR,
                              .clear_value = {0.25f, 0.5f, 0.75f, 1.0f}},
            },
        .swapchain = sglue_swapchain()});
    sg_apply_pipeline(state.pip);
    sg_apply_bindings(&state.bind);
    sg_apply_uniforms(UB_vs_params, &SG_RANGE(vs_params));
    sg_draw(0, 36, 1);
    sg_end_pass();
    sg_commit();
}

void cleanup(void) { sg_shutdown(); }

sapp_desc sokol_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;
    return (sapp_desc){
        .init_cb = init,
        .frame_cb = frame,
        .cleanup_cb = cleanup,
        .width = 800,
        .height = 600,
        .sample_count = 4,
        .window_title = "Cube (sokol-app)",
        .icon.sokol_default = true,
        .logger.func = slog_func,
    };
}



The shader (cube-sapp.glsl):

@ctype mat4 mat4
@ctype vec4 vec4

@vs vs
layout(binding=0) uniform vs_params {
    mat4 mvp;
};

in vec4 position;
in vec4 color0;

out vec4 color;

void main() {
    gl_Position = mvp * position;
    color = color0;
}
@end

@fs fs
in vec4 color;
out vec4 frag_color;

void main() {
    frag_color = color;
}
@end

@program cube vs fs

TLDR: I tried replacing HandMadeMath functions from a sokol example with cglm, and it didn't work.

does this actually involve DirectX 11?
